# How to play google Widevine DRM in Windows 8 Universal App using C#

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal, widevine

I have to build a Windows 8 Universal App for video streaming and I already use the google Widevine DRM to my videos on other platforms ( Android & iOS ). So, does Windows 10 Universal App support Widevine DRM ? if possible please share the details.

Comment: As far as I know, it seems like`DRM` is a kind of technology for video. `Widevine` is the product using this technology which google published, right? In that case, what did you actually asked? Did you ask if windows 10 platform support this product or did you ask if windows 10 universal app can play the video who use this technology?

Comment: Did windows 10 platform support this product?

Comment: It seems like yes. But only windows 10 desktop, please reference the [widevine supported platform](https://www.widevine.com/supported_platforms.html).